# Wordpress Order Archive by ACF Repeater Field Date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site that has a custom post type of Event which includes an Advanced Custom Field (ACF) Repeater field with a date field included. I am looking to order the Event Post Type on the archive view by the earliest Date Field within the ACF Repeater.

I had tried using a nested meta_query by adding the key of `dates_%_date` but the returned Events don't seem to be in the proper order. The repeater field is named `dates` and the sub_field for it is named `date`.

Does the order of the repeater fields matter? IE: does it make a difference which entry in the repeater field has the date? I'm looking to compare ALL dates from the repeater field.

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'dates_%_date',
    'compare' => '>=',
    'value' => $today
   )
);

$args['meta_key'] = 'dates_%_date';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
```

Is there anything glaringly wrong in this query? Or another way to run this?

Comment: Have you tried the steps in the docs for querying subfields using the mention method (you need to scroll down a little bit to field the sub fields section)  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30258467/2286736

Answer (score 0):

Since a repeater field starts with 0 and counts up, you need a little workaround to query and sort by a repeater value.

Try this one:

```
function dates_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace( "meta_key = 'dates_$", "meta_key LIKE 'dates_%", $where );
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'dates_where');
```

See the difference? I am replacing the equal sign with a LIKE. So from now on you can query:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'dates_$_date',
    'compare' => '>=',
    'value' => $today
   )
);

$args['order'] = 'ASC';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
```

Hope that helps for a start.